# Search box is using post title as prefix

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a problem with search box on my website. The thing is, that if someone is searching from post it's redirect him to `http://example.com/post-title/?s=test` instead of `http://example.com/?s=test`. Of course searching from **main page** is working properly.

I am using **Simple Custom Css** plugin to manage custom css. There is store my css for search box.

Here is what the search box code look:

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" style="margin-left:85px; margin-bottom:30px">
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search..." oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Error!')" required="">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: CSS doesn't come into play here.

Answer (score 0):

When you say, it works fine from the main page, give the `action` attribute and set it to the main page then:

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" action="/" style="margin-left: 85px; margin-bottom: 30px">
<!----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

This way, it will ensure that the search is always performed on the `http://example.com` rather than the current page, as an empty or non-existing `action` attribute will submit to the same page.